# Where I can learn the Kubernetes with Hands on

Tags: kubernetes

I am sorry if this question sounds silly.

**I would like to know any place where I can learn the kubernetes simple to hard way where a beginner can get the whole idea of kubernetes, from scratch until you deploy an application to aws with other tools such as `prometheus`, `stackstorm` etc.**

I know there are many Youtube videos and Udemy courses, but, I need a different source, maybe a **Github Repository**, or a **Blog** that teaches a newbie about Kubernetes from scratch to at least to the intermediate level with **commands** using **minikube**.

Thank you so much for your patience with me for a question like this but **I really appreciate this.** It is hard to find a good tutorial, videos are really boring or out of the scope sometimes.

Comment: What about a book? _Kubernetes in Action_, Manning, 2017, is a great resource where you can find everything you need to know in one place.

Comment: you could find Kubernetes in action through following url https://www.yunforum.net/pdf/kubernetes-in-action.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are really want to do it all manually you should check [Kubernetes The Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way). This tutorial does not have any automation process, you need to do all manually. Honestly I would recommend it after a few days/weeks of practicing with `Kubernetes`.

Second good place to learn `Kubernetes` is `Katakoda`. You can find there [Kubernetes](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes) and [Docker](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker) tutorials. If you want to learn Kubernetes you also **need to learn something about containers before**.

Another place is [Kubernetes Tutorials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/). Also here you can find some Tasks or Concepts. The same site contains whole K8s documentation with real examples.

For environment to run `Kubernetes` I would advise you [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/overview/). It will create you one-node cluster. Before you will need instal [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) and [Kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux).
As for beginner I would suggest to use Minikube with `--vm-driver=none`.

Last source I wanted to mentioned is [Medium](https://medium.com/). You will be able to find many tutorials for Kubernetes/Kubeadm/Minikube.

Answer (score 0):

You can try katacoda .They have provide dummy kubernetes environment.
[katacoda](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes)
.

Although kubernetes docs are enough to get to know about deployments,services,pods etc. You can try those example in katacoda environment. [Kubernetes playground](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/playground)

Katacoda also have some examples .